# Unity uploading ingame stats to a website

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, statistics

I want to make a Unity game that sends ingame stats to a website, Like how many times a player has shot, how many kills the play has. ect.

my question is is this even possible using Unity? if yes what tools do I need?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you already have a backend for your game analytics, then you can just call their API endpoints using [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html).

```cs
using UnityEngine.Networking;
...
IEnumerator LogEvent(kills, shots) {
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("kills", kills);
    form.AddField("shots", shots);

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://www.my-server.com/myform", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
...
public void GameOver() {
    ...
    StartCoroutine(LogEvent(10, 100));
}
```

2. You can use some Analytics SDKs for that such as **Firebase Analytics**, **Google Analytics**, **AppsFlyer**, and so on.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v4/devguide

In my experience, Firebase is the best one as it supports other tools like Storage, Authentication, ...